# Dynamically creating a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a script which creates a table with 4 columns. The columns are `N`, `N * 10`, `N * 100` and `N * 1000`. I managed to create the first two columns, but now I'm stuck. How should I refactor my code?

```
var n;
var m1 = 10;
var m2 = 100;
var m3 = 1000;

document.writeln("<table>");
document.writeln("<h1>Calculating Compound Interest</h1>");
document.writeln("<thead><tr><th>N</th>");
document.writeln("<th>N * 10</th>");
document.writeln("<th>N * 100</th>");
document.writeln("<th>N * 1000</th>");
document.writeln("</tr></thead><tbody>");

for (var number = 1; number <= 5; number++) {
    n = number * m1;

    if (number % 2 !== 0)
        document.writeln("<tr class='oddrow'><td>" + number +
                         "</td><td>" + n.toFixed(0) + "</td></tr>");
    else
        document.writeln("<tr><td>" + number +
                         "</td><td>" + n.toFixed(0) + "</td></tr>");
}

document.writeln("</tbody></table>");
```

Comment: You've got this far - I think you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: You can use arrays to hold the multipliers and loop through and calculate -- http://jsfiddle.net/9ztbS/

Comment: Please consider a template based databinding solution instead of manually looping out dynamic html. Look into Jquery templates, KnockoutJs or similar

Comment: @TGH Not every Javascript question requires JQuery. There is nothing wrong with looping using standard language constructs.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I understand that not every project uses or want to use other frameworks, but as soon as you need something beyond the simplest case you are starting to get code that is very hard to maintain. That is where data binding and template frameworks can help you out

Comment: However, if people ask about loops and only get JQuery answers, *how will anyone learn about loops in Javascript*, which is what the asker wanted to learn about?

Comment: Using a template framework vs using vanilla loops in JavaScript is a moot discussion. All good programmers know that the best way to generate HTML dynamically is to use a catamorphism. It makes your code easier to read, understand and maintain and ensures that your program is inherently type safe while still providing the flexibility offered by looping constructs minus the need for explicit control flow & dangerous side effects due to a single scope, variable name clashes and mutable state. It makes your program easier to reason about since you only need to concern yourself with the data flow.

Answer (score 1):

change your for loop to following:

```
for ( var number = 1; number <= 5; ++number )
 {
    n = number * m1;
    if ( number % 2 !== 0 )
       document.writeln( "<tr class='oddrow'><td>" + number + "</td>");
    else
       document.writeln( "<tr><td>" + number + "</td>");

    document.writeln("<td>" + n.toFixed(0) + "</td>" );
    n = number * m2;
    document.writeln("<td>" + n.toFixed(0) + "</td>" );
    n = number * m3;
    document.writeln("<td>" + n.toFixed(0) + "</td></tr>" );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add two more td's where you will put the result of `number*2` and `number*m3`

Also I would recommend you using innerHTML to write complete desired html rather than using `document.writeIn` every time

See [The Solution on js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samiciit/erUR9/1/)

```
 var n; 
 var m1 = 10;
 var m2 = 100;
 var m3 = 1000;

var heading_html = "<h1>Calculating Compound Interest</h1>" ;     
var tbable_html = "<table border=1>"; 

tbable_html +=   "<thead><tr><th>N</th>";
tbable_html +=  "<th>N*10</th>";
tbable_html +=  "<th>N*100</th>";
tbable_html +=  "<th>N*1000</th>";
tbable_html +="</tr></thead><tbody>";
for (var number = 1; number <= 5; ++number) {
    n1 = number * m1; 
    n2 = number * m2;
    n3 = number * m3;
    if (number % 2 !== 0)
        tbable_html +="<tr class='oddrow'><td>" + number + "</td><td>" +
n1.toFixed(0)+"</td><td>"+n2.toFixed(0)+"</td><td>"+n3.toFixed(0)+"</td></tr>";
    else
        tbable_html +="<tr><td>" + number + "</td><td>" + n1.toFixed(0) +
"</td><td>" + n2.toFixed(0) + "</td><td>" + n3.toFixed(0) + "</td></tr>";
}
tbable_html +="</tbody></table>";

document.write(heading_html+tbable_html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function (string, n) {
    return string + "<tr class='" + (n % 2 ? "oddrow" : "evenrow") + "'>" +
           [n, 10 * n, 100 * n, 1000 * n].reduce(td, "") + "</tr>";
}, "");

document.body.innerHTML += "<table><thead><tr>" +
    "<th>N</th><th>N * 10</th><th>N * 100</th><th>N * 1000</th>" +
    "</tr></thead><tbody>" + n + "</tbody></table>";

function td(string, n) {
    return string + "<td>" + n + "</td>";
}
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7uPVH/

---

If you don't want to use `.reduce` then you could rewrite the above code as follows:

```
var n = "";

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    n += "<tr class='" + (i % 2 ? "oddrow" : "evenrow") + "'>";

    n += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
    n += "<td>" + 10 * i + "</td>";
    n += "<td>" + 100 * i + "</td>";
    n += "<td>" + 1000 * i + "</td>";

    n += "</tr>";
}

document.body.innerHTML += "<table><thead><tr>" +
    "<th>N</th><th>N * 10</th><th>N * 100</th><th>N * 1000</th>" +
    "</tr></thead><tbody>" + n + "</tbody></table>";
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7uPVH/1/